# How is finding all locations in google maps within 5km of a point implemented?

Tags: database, postgresql, google-maps, maps

Imagine an enormous collection of locations of interest. And given any point on the map we would like to list all such locations within say 5 km of it.

This seems like a reasonably simple idea that I expect there is already a thought out solution. But I don't know how to Google for it.

How would the location data be stored in a database to make searching fast. I'm assuming that a SQL database (which is based around relational tabular data) will not work since I don't see an obvious way to use SQL's tabular nature to filter out most location further than 5 km away to keep each query fast.

Maybe databases like Postgres have some kind of spatial extensions that allow what I am asking to be done fast. If so how is such a thing implemented.

And if one were implementing a database from scratch for spatial queries like mine how would they be implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spatial extension for postgres is called `PostGIS`. It has special data types to represent maps and locations. Also it has special indexes to speed up the queries on spatial data (`GIN` and `GiST` indexes).

Here is a list of PostGIS Frequently Asked Questions. It has an answer for your question.
http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/PostGIS_FAQ.html